# How is reputation given/taken for multiple owners' answers?

Tags: support, reputation

On several occasions I have seen answers that belong to a list of users (abstract or real) like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514):

```
15 revs, 9 users 85% Robert Cartaino
```

When [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) owns something, no reputation point changes occur, but in this particular case, there are only real users that "own" the answer.

How are reputation points computed if such an answer is upvoted or downvoted?

**Answer based on comment:**
"Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation."

Comment: In that post it says: *Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.* which is probably the easiest solution. Do note that on [Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) there is an algorithm to gain rep from edits made to the same content by multiple users.